# Referencing local image in PlantUML salt wireframe

Tags: plantuml

I'm trying to include a local image into my PlantUML salt wireframe for my GUI documentation in Ubuntu 20.04. The [PlantUMl reference page](https://plantuml.com/de/salt) only shows how to include a http link. How to do this?

I tried the following, but I'm getting "Cannot decode" in the output.

```
@startsalt
scale 2
{

title Test Page
{S

{^"Figure"
<img:file://./pie-chart.png>
<img:file://./pie-chart.png>
<img:.\pie-chart.png>
}
..

}

}
@endsalt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the image `blah.png` at the same location as the PlantUML source, this will work:

```
@startsalt
scale 2
{

title Test Page
{S

{^"Figure"
<img:blah.png>
}
..

}

}
@endsalt
```

I get on my (windows) machine:

[image]

### Edit: WSL (Ubuntu) test

I have WSL on my Windows machine, and so I started up VSCode in Ubuntu, and installed the PlantUML plugin for VSCode. I created a file `/home/me/test/blah.png` (copied from my Windows), and then created the following PlantUML file stored in `/home/me/test.wsd`:

```
@startsalt
'scale 1
{

title Test Page
{S

{^"Figure 0"
<img:test/blah.png>
}
{^"Figure 1"
<img:./test/blah.png>
}
{^"Figure 2"
<img:"/home/me/test/blah.png">
}
{^"Figure 3"
<img src="/home/me/test/blah.png">
}
{^"Figure 4"
<img src="test/blah.png">
}
..

}

}
@endsalt
```

[image: Ubuntu (WSL) rendering]

It has relative and absolute paths, with the `src=` alternative for specifying images. I can get them all to work with png files on my Ubuntu 20 (again, using the PlantUML extension for VSCode). I should state that I have it configured to use the PlantUML server. If you're using an older version of PlantUML (Ubuntu's apt will sadly bring over an ancient one).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu an have no luck with this. Maybe png is not supported for some reason, although I would assume the jar is the same.

Comment: @k_o_ There is an alternate syntax of `<img src="file">` (and you could try .jpg). Otherwise, maybe the working directory isn't the same as the source file, in which case you'd have to pass an absolute path, e.g., `/home/me/my-puml/blah.jpg` (or wherever you put the image).

Comment: @k_o_ I remember that Ubuntu installs some 5-year-old version of PlantUML --- could that be your problem? https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/plantuml

Comment: I have downloaded the latest binaries and not used any packages from Ubuntu.

Comment: Also jpg does not work.

Comment: @k_o_ I trust you saw my edits.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comments. I updated to version v1.2022.6 and the local file mode works now. The 2021 version was not working for me.